# ARM Template - How to remove a space in a parameter string?

Tags: json, azure, templates, parameters, azure-resource-manager

I have an ARM template.
I know I can use a function called "trim" to remove spaces before and after a parameter.
But it doesn't not remove spaces inside a parameter.

e.g.
My parameter KidName contains - "Small Kid"
I want it to contain
"SmallKid"
trim(KidName) keeps the parameter with the same value.

Does anyone know or have any idea how I can do that?

Comment: I'm curious to know why the parameters have spaces in the first place? usually you save the parameters in the parameters.json file.

Comment: I took a string with " "

Comment: Have you tried the solution below?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked Replace function?

it could be something like this:

```
[replace(parameters(yourString'),' ', '')]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string#replace